# Consistency of formatting available for VSCode and Atom?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, atom-editor, atom-beautify

Some of our team uses Atom and some of our team uses VSCode. My issue is with code formatting via Atom Beautify vs VSCode formatting. They yield results that are inconsistent between each other, which is heck for version control and consistency within our team and style guides. Is there are way to attain consistency with formatting between these two IDEs?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Beautify extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify), which gives you more control over the settings.

Alternatively, you could talk to your team about adopting [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) via [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), which is a more straightforward, but also more opinionated formatter.

Answer (score 1):

[EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) helps developers define and maintain consistent coding styles between different editors and IDEs. When a project contains an `.editorconfig` file, the editor's preferences will be ignored, so they'll be intact for other projects. Plugins are available for [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/editorconfig), [Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig) and many [other editors](https://editorconfig.org/#download).